# How can I set the value of a DropDownList using jQuery by checking the value ends with a specific string?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I need to be able to select a value in a dropdownlist by the first option that ends in a specific string.

If I have three options...

**Peas**

**Cheese**

**Fleas**

... I want to be able to select the option ending in 'ese'. I need this to be case insensitive too.

Something like **$("#mydropdownlist").val().match("ese$");**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("option[value$='ese']:first").attr("selected","selected");
```

**source:** http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

**online demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tg4S2/

Comment: Thanks - do you know how to make this case insensitive?

Comment: I never new about jsfiddle - bonus. Thanks.

Comment: Am afraid not, for case case insensitive you would need to create a custom selector (http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/custom-jquery-selectors.html), sorry i missed that, let me check if i can update my answer.